# How to process many messages in parallel in mqtt

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, mqtt

I want to receive messages from many sensors (in the code I've tried from two) and process these messages in parallel by sending a command to the lights at the same time if the two sensors return "1". So I've done that in a separate thread but it doesn't work. It stops sending to the bedroom once someone enters the kitchen!

```
from class_light import Light
from test_class import Mqtt
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import sys
import threading
import time
from MongoDB import is_circadian_Light


Broker            = "broker.mqttdashboard.com"
username          = "growthtechnology"
password          = "growthtechnology"
PortaBroker       = 1883
KeepAliveBroker   = 60
client_name       = "Local"

topic_sub = "testtopic/1" 
topic_pub = "testtopic/3"

light = Mqtt()
occupancy_sensor = [("testtopic/4", 0), ("testtopic/5", 0)]
tunable_light = Light("deviceID")

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connection to the broker. Result : "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic_sub)
    client.subscribe(occupancy_sensor)

def on_publish(client,userdata,result):
    print("Message published")

def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):
    if rc != 0:
        print("Unexpected disconnection.")

try:
    print("[STATUS] Inicializando MQTT...")
    #inicializing MQTT:
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.username_pw_set(username, password)
    client.on_connect     = on_connect
    client.on_message     = light.message()
    client.on_disconnect  = on_disconnect
    client.on_publish     = on_publish

    client.connect(Broker, PortaBroker, KeepAliveBroker)

    def publishing():
        while True:
            msg = light.messages # calling for the variable "messages" to get PUBLISH messages
            print(msg)
            time.sleep(3)
            topic = light.topic
            if msg == "1" and topic == "testtopic/4":
                if is_circadian_Light("device2") == 1 :
                    client.publish("testtopic/Bedroom",tunable_light.circadianLight())
                    time.sleep(10)
    def publishing_kitchen():
        while True:
            msg_kitchen = light.messages 
            topic = light.topic
            if msg_kitchen == "1" and topic == "testtopic/5":
                if is_circadian_Light("device2") == 1 :
                    client.publish("testtopic/Kitchen",tunable_light.circadianLight())
                    time.sleep(10)

                #code to turn off lights after 1 min

    pub = threading.Thread(target= publishing)
    pub.start()
    pub_k = threading.Thread(target= publishing_kitchen)
    pub_k.start()
    client.loop_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("\nCtrl+C pressionado, encerrando aplicacao e saindo...")
    sys.exit(0)
```

This the class Mqtt that I have created:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time


class Mqtt():

    def __init__(self, messages = "", topic = "", topic_1 = ""):
        self._messages = messages
        self._topic = topic

    @property
    def messages(self):
        return self._messages

    @messages.setter
    def messages(self, messages):
        self._messages = messages

    @property
    def topic(self):
        return self._topic

    @topic.setter
    def topic(self, topic):
        self._topic = topic

    def message(self):
        def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
            Message = str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8"))
            self._messages = Message
            if msg.topic == "testtopic/4":
            self._topic = msg.topic
            print("[Receiving msg] Topic:" +msg.topic+" / Message: "+Message)
        return on_message
```

Comment: You have a 10 second timing window you drive a freight train through

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what should I do. @hardillb

Comment: did you tried publish.multiple(messages)? i would do it like having a flag for each topic and setting the flag as 1 whenever it will receive a message in on_message() and on the other hand push the topics in that array and then publish it by publish.multiple([array]).

Comment: yes I tried it and it gave me this error:```[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it``` @Hsn

Comment: can you share your whole code?which i can run?